# Django, в views.py приходит пустой POST запрос из формы

Tags: python, html, django, post, запрос

есть html-страничка с формой (bootstrap5) и кнопка для отправки, но во views.py запрос прилетает без полей формы.
Код views.py

```
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def new_record(request):
    record_item = Record()
    #record_item.save()
    if request.method == "GET":
        new_rec_form = NewRecordForm([record_item], initial={'id': record_item.id})
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        new_rec_form = NewRecordForm([record_item], data=request.POST, initial={'id': record_item.id})
        if new_rec_form.is_valid():
            #print("valid")
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
        #else:
            #print(new_rec_form.errors)
            #print("not valid")
            #emp =
            #record_item.employer = request.POST.get("employer")

    context = {'record': record_item, 'form': new_rec_form}
    return render(request, 'new_record.html', context=context)
```

Код формы:

```
    <form action="/new_record/" method="post" id="id_NewRecordForm" class="row" data-url="{% url 'ajax_load_data' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.id %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.serial_number %}

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.inv_number %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.acc_inv_number %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.batch %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.type %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row model_select">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.model %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.company %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.office %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.cabinet %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.status %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.employer %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row rec_row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% bootstrap_field form.description %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1 buttons">
                <button type="button" id="change_button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="change_data()">Сохранить
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 buttons">
                <button type="submit" id="send_button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Отправить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

В коде страницы у тега input есть аттрибуты name, но в теле POST-запрос их нет.
Вывод в консоли

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['39lGQ3eBCggi9hkzaMTmu4mQVHHcgeCa0TzPK5BQgNGW5FHLonq3znYkGNAiMLSX']}>
[04/Jan/2023 18:37:41] "POST /new_record/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12138
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. В моей реализации была кнопка, которая выставляла полям аттрибут `disabled`. Такие поля не попадают в POST-запрос, поэтому они теперь `readonly` и всё работает